Moment generating function for Hypergeometric Distribution
For reference,

$$P_{X}(k)=\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-n}{K-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$
${\displaystyle N}$ is the population size
${\displaystyle K}$ is the number of success states in the population
${\displaystyle n}$ is the number of draws (i.e. quantity drawn in
each trial)
${\displaystyle k}$ is the number of observed successes
$X$ is the random variable

The MGF is given as follows(which is quite intimidating);
$$M_{X}(t)=\frac{\binom{N-K}{n}{}_2 F_1\left(-n,-k;N-K-n+1;e^t\right)}{\binom{N}{n}}$$
I wanted to derive this so I read through and found, $$M_{X}(t)=E[e^{tx}]=\underset{x}\sum e^{tx}f(x)$$
So this means,
$$M_{X}(t)=\sum_{x=0}^n e^{tx}\frac{\binom{K}{x}\binom{N-n}{K-x}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$
$$M_{X}(t)=\frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}}\sum_{x=0}^n e^{tx}{\binom{K}{x}\binom{N-n}{K-x}}$$
I can't seem to find any identity or trick that solves this sum and how does it all end up with such a complicated MGF;
$$\sum_{x=0}^n e^{tx}{\binom{K}{x}\binom{N-n}{K-x}}=\binom{N-K}{n}{}_2 F_1\left(-n,-k;N-K-n+1;e^t\right)$$
I want to understand different ways to arrive at the moment generating function for the hypergeometric distribution

First little note is that your reference is not quite right: looking here the PMF is (in your notation from later on):
$$ P_X(x) = \frac{\binom{K}{x}\binom{N-K}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}} = \frac{\binom{n}{x}\binom{N-n}{K-x}}{\binom{N}{K}}, $$
so you have possibly mixed up the two versions. Then what we want to prove is
$$ \binom{N-K}{n}\,_2F_1(-n,-K; N-K-n+1;e^t) = \sum_{x=0}^ne^{tx}\binom{K}{x}\binom{N-K}{n-x}. $$
You can solve this by unpacking the definition of the hypergeometric function. As here we have:
$$ _2F_1(-n,-K; N-K-n+1;e^t) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(-n)_x(-K)_x}{(N-K-n+1)_x}\frac{e^{tx}}{x!}, $$
where the Pochhammer symbol or rising factorial is (for $x>0$ an integer)
$$(m)_x = m(m+1)\cdots (m+x-1) = \frac{(m+x-1)!}{(m-1)!}. $$
For a negative argument, we can convert the Pochhammer symbols into factorials (to get us closer to the MGF we want):
$$ (-m)_x = (-m)(-m+1)\cdots(-m+x-1) = (-1)^x\frac{m!}{(m-x)!} $$
Note that the infinite sum terminates because each term gets a 0. The above gets us:
$$ _2F_1(-n,-K; N-K-n+1;e^t) = \sum_{x=0}^n\frac{n!K!(N-n+K)!}{(n-x)!(K-x)!(N-n+K-x)!}\frac{e^{tx}}{x!}. $$
Multiplying everything by $\binom{N-K}{n}$, the $x^\text{th}$ term is:
$$ \frac{(N-K)!n!K!(N-n-K)!}{(N-K-n)!n!x!(n-x)!(K-x)!(N-n-K-x)!}e^{tx} = \binom{K}{x}\binom{N-K}{n-x}e^{tx} $$
as required.

Thank you very much, yes i mixed up the notation, that did confuse me as well
